# Compare Hour and minute of the days in a weeks in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to compare hour and minute and print like below:

E.g:

> - Sunday: 10:30 .a.m. - 6:00 .p.m.
> - Monday: 10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.
> - Tuesday: 10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.
> - Wednesday: 10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.
> - Thursday: 10:00 .a.m. - 9:00 .p.m.
> - Friday: 10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.
> - Saturday: 10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.

Compare and print:

> - Mon-Web:10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.
> - Thu:10:00 .a.m. - 9:00 .p.m.
> - Fri-Sat:10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.
> - Sun: 10:30 .a.m. - 6:00 .p.m.

if all are same:

> - Mon-Sat:10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.
> - Sun: 10:00 .a.m. - 8:00 .p.m.

here is code i use, it just compare if it change 1 day:

```
$value['hours'] = [{"day":"Sunday","status":"1","open":{"hour":"09","minute":"00"},"close":{"hour":"21","minute":"00"}},{"day":"Monday","status":"1","open":{"hour":"09","minute":"00"},"close":{"hour":"19","minute":"00"}},{"day":"Tuesday","status":"1","open":{"hour":"09","minute":"00"},"close":{"hour":"21","minute":"00"}},{"day":"Wednesday","status":"1","open":{"hour":"09","minute":"00"},"close":{"hour":"21","minute":"00"}},{"day":"Thursday","status":"1","open":{"hour":"09","minute":"00"},"close":{"hour":"21","minute":"00"}},{"day":"Friday","status":"1","open":{"hour":"09","minute":"00"},"close":{"hour":"21","minute":"00"}},{"day":"Saturday","status":"1","open":{"hour":"09","minute":"00"},"close":{"hour":"21","minute":"00"}}];

if (!function_exists('dateCheck')) {
    function dateCheck($arr) {
        $location = array();
        $locacheck = array();
        $firstValue = current($arr);
        $check = '';
        if(($firstValue != $arr[1]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[2]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[3]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[4]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[5])) {
            return $check = 'Mon';
        } elseif(($firstValue != $arr[1]) && ($arr[2] == $firstValue) && ($arr[2] == $arr[3]) && ($arr[2] == $arr[4]) && ($arr[2] == $arr[5])) {
            return $check = 'Tue';
        } elseif(($firstValue != $arr[2]) && ($arr[1] == $firstValue) && ($arr[1] == $arr[3]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[4]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[5])) {
            return $check = "Wed";
        } elseif(($firstValue != $arr[3]) && ($arr[1] == $firstValue) && ($arr[1] == $arr[2]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[4]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[5])) {
            return $check = "Thu";
        } elseif(($firstValue != $arr[4]) && ($arr[1] == $firstValue) && ($arr[1] == $arr[2]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[3]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[5])) {
            return $check = "Fri";
        } elseif(($firstValue != $arr[5]) && ($arr[1] == $firstValue) && ($arr[1] == $arr[2]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[3]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[4])) {
            return $check = "Sat";
        } elseif(($arr[5] == $arr[1]) && ($arr[1] == $firstValue) && ($arr[1] == $arr[2]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[3]) && ($arr[1] == $arr[4])) {
            return $check = 'Same';
        }
    }
}

<?php $hours = json_decode($value['hours']);
                        $openhour = array();
                        $openminute = array();
                        $closehour = array();
                        $closeminute = array();
                        foreach ($hours as $hour) {
                            if ($hour->day == 'Sunday') {
                                continue;
                            }
                            array_push($openhour, intval($hour->open->hour));
                            array_push($openminute, intval($hour->open->minute));
                            array_push($closehour, intval($hour->close->hour));
                            array_push($closeminute, intval($hour->close->minute));
                        }
                        $checkopenhour = dateCheck($openhour);
                        $checkopenminute = dateCheck($openminute);
                        $checkclosehour = dateCheck($closehour);
                        $checkcloseminute = dateCheck($closeminute);

                        if($checkopenhour == 'Same' && $checkopenminute == 'Same' && $checkclosehour == 'Same' && $checkcloseminute == 'Same') {
                            echo '<tr><td><p>Mon-Sat:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                        } else {
                            if($checkopenhour == 'Mon' || $checkclosehour == 'Mon') {
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Mon:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[2]->open->hour).':'.$hours[2]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[2]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[2]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Tue-Sat:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                            } elseif($checkopenhour == 'Tue' || $checkclosehour == 'Tue') {
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Mon-Sat:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Tue:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[2]->open->hour).':'.$hours[2]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[2]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[2]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                            } elseif($checkopenhour == 'Wed' || $checkclosehour == 'Wed') {
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Mon-Tue:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Wed:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[3]->open->hour).':'.$hours[3]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[3]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[3]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Thu-Sat:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                            } elseif($checkopenhour == 'Thu' || $checkclosehour == 'Thu') {
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Mon-Wed:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Thu:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[4]->open->hour).':'.$hours[4]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[4]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[4]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Fri-Sat:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                            } elseif($checkopenhour == 'Fri' || $checkclosehour == 'Fri') {
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Mon-Thu:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Fri:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[5]->open->hour).':'.$hours[5]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[5]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[5]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Sat:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                            } elseif($checkopenhour == 'Sat' || $checkclosehour == 'Sat') {
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Mon-Fri:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[1]->open->hour).':'.$hours[1]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[1]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[1]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                                echo '<tr><td><p>Sat:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[6]->open->hour).':'.$hours[6]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[6]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[6]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                            }
                        }
                        echo '<tr><td><p>Sun:</p></td><td style="padding-left:5px;"><p>'.intval($hours[0]->open->hour).':'.$hours[0]->open->minute.' a.m. - '.($hours[0]->close->hour%12).':'.$hours[0]->close->minute.' p.m.</p></td></tr>';
                        ?>
```

Comment: What are you comparing?

Comment: comparing hour and minute between the days. OpenHour:OpenMinute - CloseHour:CloseMinute

Comment: Where are you having trouble with this task?

Comment: i dont know how to compare if it change 2 or 3 or multi days, if it just change 1 day, i can compare it

Comment: See code i have just update